# (Laravel4) trying to print out tags

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I'm new to laravel and php and i have a hard time understanding the 'relationships'.

I'm trying to add tags to each tutorial in my database (which could just be seen as posts).

When i try to print out all the tags for 1 tutorial i just get one tag while i have 2 tags asigned to it.

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $tags = Tutorial::where('id', '=', 1)->first()->tags()->get();
    //$tags = $tutorial->tags()->get();


    return View::make('home', array(
        'tags' => $tags
    ));
}
```

Tutorial model:

```
class Tutorial extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'tutorials';

    public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'tutorials_tags', 'tag_id');
    }
}
```

tag model:

```
class Tag extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'tags';
    public function Tutorials() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tutorial', 'tutorials_tags', 'tutorial_id');
    }
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($tags as $tags)
    {{$tags->name}}
@endforeach
```

My database looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/GIbqAGE.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your loop is causing the trouble, you are replacing the array with an item in the array with the loop:

```php
@foreach($tags as $tags)
    {{$tags->name}}
@endforeach
```

Try change it to:

```php
@foreach($tags as $tag)
    {{$tag->name}}
@endforeach
```

---

**Update:** Another problem is that you're referencing the wrong foreign key.

In Many-to-Many relationship, when you use `$this->belongsToMany()`, the third argument that asks for a foreign key is basically asking "Which column of the pivot table, aka. `tutorials_tags` table that I should match with this `Tutorial` model?". Which of course should be 
 `tutorial_id`.

In your case when you specified `tag_id` in your Tutorial's `tags()` method, it makes Laravel think that `tag_id` is your tutorial id, which is wrong. `Tutorial` should be looked up in the pivot table as `tutorial_id`.

So your `public function tags()` would actually need to be:

```php
public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'tutorials_tags', 'tutorial_id');
}
```

Or as a bonus point, if you look at Laravel source code, it would do:

```php
$foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();
```

And `getForeignKey()` does `return snake_case(class_basename($this)).'_id';` which, in turn, returns `"tutorial_id"`.

Since you are already conforming to Laravel's standard of naming tables and foreign keys, you can just omit the third parameter like this:

```php
public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'tutorials_tags');
}
```

This goes the same as the `$otherKey` which asks "Which column of the pivot table, aka. `tutorials_tags` table that I should match with the `Tag` model?"
So it would be `tag_id`.

So we are done with `Tutorial` model. Now, let's apply to the `Tag` model. So in `Tag` model should be:

```php
public function tutorials() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tutorial', 'tutorials_tags', `tag_id`);
}
```

Comment: Nope, it is still only printing one tag, while i have 2 tags assigned. :-\ Thanks tho

Comment: Try `$this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'tutorials_tags', 'tutorial_id');` or `$this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'tutorials_tags', 'tutorial_id', 'tag_id');` in your Tutorial::tags(). That's what http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many seems to suggest.

Comment: Lol, those do both work. And i still have no idea what i'm doing xD
Thank you

Comment: Ok.. I'm updating the answer and will explain the cause as well. :)

Comment: @Dieter91 I updated the answer with some explanation. Feel free to accept or not if it answers your question!